# Does main.py or app.yaml determine the URL used by the App Engine cron task in this example?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, url-routing

In this sample code the URL of the app seems to be determined by this line within the app:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/mailjob', MailJob)], debug=True)
```

but also by this line within the app handler of app.yaml:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

However, the URL of the cron task is set by this line:

```
url: /tasks/summary
```

So it seems the cron utility will call "`/tasks/summary`" and because of the app handler, this will cause `main.py` to be invoked. Does this mean that, as far as the cron is concerned, the line in the app that sets the URL is extraneous:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/mailjob', MailJob)], debug=True)
```

. . . since the only URL needed by the cron task is the one defined in app.yaml.

```
app.yaml
application: yourappname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: main.py

cron.yaml
cron:
    - description: daily mailing job
    url: /tasks/summary
    schedule: every 24 hours

main.py
#!/usr/bin/env python  

import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch 

class MailJob(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        # Call your website using URL Fetch service ...
        url = "http://www.yoursite.com/page_or_service"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)

        if result.status_code == 200:
            doSomethingWithResult(result.content)

        # Send emails using Mail service ...
        mail.send_mail(sender="admin@gmail.com",
                to="someone@gmail.com",
                subject="Your account on YourSite.com has expired",
                body="Bla bla bla ...")
        return

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
        ('/mailjob', MailJob)], debug=True)

def main():
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
app.yaml
application: yourappname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /tasks/.*
  script: main.py

cron.yaml
cron:
    - description: daily mailing job
    url: /tasks/summary
    schedule: every 24 hours

main.py
#!/usr/bin/env python  

import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch 

class MailJob(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        # Call your website using URL Fetch service ...
        url = "http://www.yoursite.com/page_or_service"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)

        if result.status_code == 200:
                doSomethingWithResult(result.content)

        # Send emails using Mail service ...
        mail.send_mail(sender="admin@gmail.com",
                        to="someone@gmail.com",
                        subject="Your account on YourSite.com has expired",
                        body="Bla bla bla ...")
        return

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
        ('/tasks/summary', MailJob)], debug=True)

def main():
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're reading [this page](http://basbrun.com/?p=101) (even though you don't give us the URL). The configuration and code as presented won't run successfully: the cron task will try to visit URL path /tasks/summary, app.yaml will make that execute main.py, but the latter only sets up a handler for /mailjob, so the cron task's attempt will fail with a 404 status code.

Comment: Enough context was provided without adding the URL. You're being cranky and making an unnecessary fuss.

Comment: @David, the URL would have helped -- I had to locate it with a search to confirm that the code & config there are indeed incomplete, so the answer to the question as posed in the title is "neither this main.py nor this app.yaml define what code should run to serve that URL" (i.e., as presented, this set of code and config files just won't run successfully).